# Reading .VTS Files in Mayavi/ Python Scripting

Tags: python, 3d, vtk, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I'm new to python and have a structured grid vtk file (.VTS) that I would like to open in a python script (visual studio code) to run in mayavi. I've been reading elsewhere you need a XML data reader to load the source data? What's the easiest way to open this in mayavi and begin to manipulate the data.

I've installed mayavi to my virtual environment, but wondering if I need other packages.

Any information or recommendation for articles to read/things to try would be greatly appreciated!

Information from the VTS file header

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="StructuredGrid" version="1.0" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt64">
<StructuredGrid WholeExtent="0 72 0 1023 0 255">
<Piece Extent="0 72 0 1023 0 255">
<Points>
<DataArray Name="points" NumberOfComponents="3" type="Float64" format="appended" offset="0"/>
</Points>
<PointData Scalars="gpr data">
<DataArray Name="gpr data" NumberOfComponents="1" type="Float64" format="appended" offset="459276296"/>
</PointData>
</Piece>
</StructuredGrid>
<AppendedData encoding="raw">
```

Comment: You can use the built-in [`xml`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) module, or the excellent [`lxml`](https://lxml.de) (which I prefer).

Comment: Hi thanks! I just installed lxml to my venv. Do you have a link to a document explaining the functions? Such as one to read my .VTS file. I'm planning to manipulate it in mlab once loaded.

Comment: At the link I provided, there's a [tutorial](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html) on `lxml.etree` that should be helpful. Their documentation is good, and there are tons of questions here on Stack Overflow about working with the module as well.